# Is it possible to create Criteria Query without defining a root?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Is it possible to create Criteria Query without defining a root? Or should I always define at least one root?

**Updated**:

I've tried to do this and I've had an `IllegalStateException - no criteria query roots were specified`

But I wonder if there are any chances to make a criteria query without defining a root?

Comment: Have you tried a query without a root?

Comment: Yes. And I had an IllegalStateException - no criteria query roots were specified. But I wonder if there are any chances to make a criteria query without defining a root?

Comment: and how would you do a standard string-based JPQL query without a "root" (aka candidate) ?

Comment: @NeilStockton there is no way of doing this in JPQL, yes, but if criteria api can autodetect root by defined type, for example?

Comment: JPQL and Criteria sit together, providing the same possibilities. If you can't do it in one then you can't in the other. End of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible. According to the JPA (2) spec, a CriteriaQuery must have at least one root.

EDIT: I was hoping to find a definitive reference in §6.5.2 (Query Roots) of the JPA 2 spec, but it is inconclusive on that point. However I recall a question on the OCE JPA developer exam, where exactly this question was asked and 'one or more roots' was the right answer. Sorry, this is the best reference I can provide.

EDIT 2: The BNF notation from §4.14, as suggested by @wypieprz, is probably a better reference :) A query has to have one or more `FROM` clauses. Since Criteria API is more or less a different notation for JPQL, all restrictions of JPQL must apply to the Criteria API as well.

Comment: Is that it: **6.5.2 Query Roots** _A CriteriaQuery object defines a query over **one** or more entity_ ?

Comment: I was thinking of 6.5.2 as well, but it really reads inconclusive. I have been certified as OCE JPA dev couple of weeks ago and still firmly remember the question there, 'one or more roots' was the right answer. Sorry, this is the best reference I can provide yet.

Comment: Chapter **4.14 BNF** of JPA 2.0 spec provides the complete BNF notation for the JPQL which plays an analogous role to the Criteria API. It is clearly stated that `from` clause is mandatory thus `Root<T>` is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks, wypieprz. Have added the reference to the answer.